# MongoDB/Mongoose - $lookup with pipeline: error code 9 but no error message

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use MongoDB with Mongoose as interface. I'm running the following aggregation query:

```
let words = ['some', 'words', 'here']

PagesModel.aggregate([

  // match the records from document
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {title: {$in: words}},
        {description: {$in: words}},
        {raw_content: {$in: words}},
      ]
    },
  },

  // load a relationship via $lookup
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'domains',
      localField: 'domain',
      foreignField: '_id',
      pipeline: [ {$limit: 1} ], // <-- it fails if I add this
      as: 'domain',
    }
  }
])
.then(d=>console.log(d))
.catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

It always fails when inside `$lookup` I add `pipeline`. The JSON error message is:

```
{
  "operationTime": "6910550388684881932",
  "ok": 0,
  "code": 9,
  "codeName": "FailedToParse",
  "$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": "6910550388684881932",
    "signature": {
      "hash": "qJgFQLITmajiZx2PT/9G1Le+frw=",
      "keyId": "6908352396221480963"
    }
  },
  "name": "MongoError"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I properly debug this code? `FailedToParse` doesn't help me do it.

Comment: Refer this document [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), there are 2 ways, one you can use only localField and foreignField, second is you can use let and pipeline, if you need to pass localField to pipeline then use `let`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What I was doing wrong**

Thanks to @turivishal for his comment. As of MongoDB 3.6 `$lookup` can be used strictly in one of two ways (I was trying to use a little from mode 1 and a little from mode 2, which is not supported). I had to do this:

```
// load a relationship via $lookup
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'domains',
    // localField: 'domain',
    // foreignField: '_id',
    let: { domain: 'domain' } // pass local field to pipeline
    pipeline: [ {$limit: 1} ], 
    as: 'domain',
  }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries

**Debugging in Mongoose**

The error message *is there*, I had to manually access it:

```
PagesModel.aggregate(...)

.then(d=>console.log(d))

.catch(e=>console.log( e.message )) // tadaa
```