# How to fix the error "must specify 'pipeline' when 'from' is empty" in Mongodb aggregation query with java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm receiving this error in my Mongodb aggregate query in my java application.

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9 (FailedToParse): 'must specify 'pipeline' when 'from' is empty' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "must specify 'pipeline' when 'from' is empty", "code": 9, "codeName": "FailedToParse"}
```

Below is my Mongo query from  Mongo shell and it works fine and giving me the results.

```
db.borrower_details.aggregate([

{
    $lookup:{
        from: "student_details",   
        localField: "student_id",  
        foreignField: "student_id",
        as: "borrow_std"     
    }
},

{
    $lookup:{
        from: "book_details", 
        localField: "book_id", 
        foreignField: "book_id",
        as: "borrow_std_book"
    }
},
{   
    $project:{
        student_id : 1,
        borrowed_from : 1,
        book_title : "$borrow_std_book.Book_Title",
    } 
}]};
```

However below is my java code and it does not works and it gives me the above mentioned exception.

```
 MongoCollection<Document> borrower_details = db.getCollection("borrower_details");


        BasicDBObject joinFields1 = new BasicDBObject();
        joinFields1.append("from", "student_details");
        joinFields1.append("localField", "student_id");
        joinFields1.append("foreignField", "student_id");
        joinFields1.append("as", "borrow_std");
        BasicDBObject lookup1 = new BasicDBObject();
        lookup1.append("$lookup", joinFields1);

        BasicDBObject joinFields2 = new BasicDBObject();
        joinFields1.append("from", "book_details");
        joinFields1.append("localField", "book_id");
        joinFields1.append("foreignField", "book_id");
        joinFields1.append("as", "borrow_std_book");
        BasicDBObject lookup2 = new BasicDBObject();
        lookup2.append("$lookup", joinFields2);

        BasicDBObject retriveFields = new BasicDBObject();
        retriveFields.append("student_id", 1);
        retriveFields.append("borrowed_from", 1);
        retriveFields.append("book_title", "$borrow_std_book.book_title");

        BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject();
        project.append("$project", retriveFields);

        List<BasicDBObject> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
        queryList.add(lookup1);
        queryList.add(lookup2);
        queryList.add(project);

        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = borrower_details.aggregate(queryList).iterator();
```

What is the issue in my java code?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456741/mongodb-mongoose-lookup-with-pipeline-error-code-9-but-no-error-message

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and it's a silly mistake from me.
If you check the given code you can see that I'm using the `joinFields1` object in the assignments when I actually want to use the `joinFields2` object. Therefore at the querying time there are no fields in the `joinFields2` object. So the fix is

```
        MongoDatabase db = DbConnection.getMongoConnection();
        MongoCollection<Document> borrower_details = db.getCollection("borrower_details");


        BasicDBObject joinFields1 = new BasicDBObject();
        joinFields1.append("from", "student_details");
        joinFields1.append("localField", "student_id");
        joinFields1.append("foreignField", "student_id");
        joinFields1.append("as", "borrow_std");

        BasicDBObject lookup1 = new BasicDBObject();
        lookup1.append("$lookup", joinFields1);

        BasicDBObject joinFields2 = new BasicDBObject();
        joinFields2.append("from", "book_details");
        joinFields2.append("localField", "book_id");
        joinFields2.append("foreignField", "book_id");
        joinFields2.append("as", "borrow_std_book");
        BasicDBObject lookup2 = new BasicDBObject();
        lookup2.append("$lookup", joinFields2);

        BasicDBObject retriveFields = new BasicDBObject();
        retriveFields.append("student_id", 1);
        retriveFields.append("borrowed_from", 1);
        retriveFields.append("borrowed_to", 1);
        retriveFields.append("actual_return_date", 1);
        retriveFields.append("student_name", "$borrow_std.student_name");
        retriveFields.append("book_title", "$borrow_std_book.book_title");

        BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject();
        project.append("$project", retriveFields);

        List<BasicDBObject> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
        queryList.add(lookup1);
        queryList.add(lookup2);
        queryList.add(project);

        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = borrower_details.aggregate(queryList).iterator();

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            Document rs = cursor.next();
            /*
              data retrieval
             */
        }
```